# How to pass cubit and state as parameter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a generic dialog that I use for everything, such as login and logout. The constructor looks like this

```
GenericDialog({
  required String dialogTitle, 
  required Widget dialogContent,
});
```

Now I'm trying to add BlocConsumer into the dialog, in order for it to work, I need to pass Cubit and State into the constructor. Below are the cubit and state I had prepared

```
abstract class BaseState extends Equatable
class LoginState extends BaseState
class LogoutState extends BaseState

abstract class BaseCubit<S> extends Cubit<S>
class LoginCubit extends BaseCubit<LoginState>
class LogoutCubit extends BaseCubit<LogoutState>
```

Below is the constructor

```
GenericDialog({
  required String dialogTitle, 
  required Widget dialogContent,
  required BaseCubit cubit,
  required BaseState state,
});
```

how i use it

```
GenericDialog({
  dialogTitle: 'LOGIN', 
  dialogContent: widget,
  cubit: LoginCubit,
  state: LoginState,
});
```

When i pass the cubit and state into the constructor, i get

```
The argument type 'Type' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BaseCubit<dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 0):

`abstract class BaseCubit<S> extends Cubit<S>` should be `abstract class BaseCubit extends Cubit<BaseState>`.
Inside constructor of `LoginCubit` you will pass `: super(LoginState)`. Same with `LogoutCubit`.

I think you should use `BlocConsumer<T, BaseState>` to access cubit inside `GenericDialog`.
And dialog would be `GenericDialog<T extends BaseCubit> extends ... {}`
Then outside dialog you should create your cubit using `BlocProvider(...)`.

You will call `GenericDialog<LoginCubit>({ dialogTitle: 'LOGIN', dialogContent: widget })`.

#### Source

I did something like that with [my own project](https://github.com/kirasok/random_password_generator/blob/master/lib/ui/widget/checkbox.dart)

Comment: Hmm, is there anyway to pass along LoginState too? Actually every page in my app also have it's own state, using base state won't work..

Comment: I think you can check if `state is LoginState` inside builder or use `BlocProvider.of<T>(context).state` to access state.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, this works for me

To pass cubit and state to another class, you have to declare the class like this

```
class YourClassName<T extends Cubit<S>, S> {
  const YourClassName();
}
```

To pass cubit and state to function, you have to declare fucntion like this

```
void YourFunctionName<T extends Cubit<S>, S> {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: if I want to give any specific state to a widget as a parameter, generic type works or we need to use another way? Just worried...

Comment: Hmm,  sounds like you are looking for BlocBuilder